# Some numeric madness

Tags: swift, math, numbers, protocols

Recently I wrote some helper functions for standard math operations(+,-,*,/) to process statistics without retardation, so explicit cast of numerics are unneeded

```swift
Double(8)/Double(3) // can be written as 8/3
```

It worked without a hassle, until I spot some erroneous behavior of a division operator, that is:

```swift
func / <F: BinaryFloatingPoint, I: BinaryInteger>(lhs: F, rhs: I) -> F {
    return lhs / F(rhs)
}
func / <F: BinaryFloatingPoint, I: BinaryInteger>(lhs: I, rhs: F) -> F {
    return rhs / F(lhs)
}

let a = 10.0
let b: UInt8 = 8

print(a/b) //outputs 1.25
print(b/a) //THIS is where weird stuff shows because it outputs 1.25 as well, but should 0.8!!
```

Is there something I missing or could it be a bug?

Comment: The line `return rhs / F(lhs)` should be `return F(lhs) / rhs`.

Comment: Some googling quickly reveals that BinaryFloatingPoint doesn't support conversion from a BinaryInteger so it's not a bug but rather a missing feature.

Comment: @joakim But why does this even compile?

Comment: Madness?!! [This is Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7AinOjDiNQ)

Answer (score 0):

It was I little skid with position of operands. The valid code is:

```swift
func / <F: BinaryFloatingPoint, I: BinaryInteger>(lhs: F, rhs: I) -> F {
    return lhs / F(rhs)
}
func / <F: BinaryFloatingPoint, I: BinaryInteger>(lhs: I, rhs: F) -> F {
    return F(lhs) / rhs
}
let a = 10.0
let b: UInt8 = 8

print(a/b) //1.25
print(b/a) //0.8
```